# Increasing itertools.permutations performance

Tags: python, performance, python-itertools

I am completing a problem where I have create a function that takes a positive integer and returns the next bigger number that can be formed by rearranging its digits. For example: 12 --> 21, 513 --> 531, 12435 --> 12453, 9817121211 --> 9817122111.

I've recompiled my code over and over increasing performance but have eventually come unto a stop where I can't get it any faster. Does anyone have any advice? Its the itertools.permutations line which is taking the vast majority of the time.

```
def next_bigger(n):
    num = str(n)
    num1 = set(int(x) for x in str(num))
    if num == num[0] *len(num):
        return -1
    #full_set = set(num)
    lis = set(int(''.join(nums)) for nums in itertools.permutations(num, len(num)))   
    lis = sorted(lis)
    try:
        return int(lis[lis.index(n)+1])
    except Exception:
        return -1
```

Link to problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/55983863da40caa2c900004e/train/python

Comment: the advice is, permutations is still bruteforcing your way through this. it's no point blaming the performance of an implementation where the algorithm being used itself is suboptimal. So, the question to you then: what's a "smarter" way to do this?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh , are you referring to a smarter way to do the permutations or do you think that I am going down a blind alley by this overall method. I have tried to write a code whereby the itertools only gives back solutions where the first number is at least as high as num[0] but could get this to work.

Comment: If I asked you to do this task, as a human, not a computer, how would you do it? You probably wouldn't start brute-forcing your way through every possible permutation of digits. Try it by hand, and use the insights gained to write a better program.

Comment: Indeed, a smarter algorithm than going through all the permutations would give the best speed-up.

However, if you need to stay with the permutations approach, there's a couple of speed-ups that can be done here: skip computing the `set` (you don't care about duplicates here), discard smaller numbers as soon as possible (using an if clause in the comprehension), then use `min` to find the next number rather than sorting. You can also try skipping the `int` in the loop, which may be faster or slower.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for the advice. Changed my code around as per your suggestions. Have answered below.

Comment: Unfortunately, the unit tests provided in the [codewars kata question link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55983863da40caa2c900004e/train/python) are mostly **trivial flips** of the first two digits, or involve a flip of **only two digits** and no other steps. So the tests don't remotely cover all the _patterns_ of numbers to embiggen. Add these two for any solutions posted: `assert next_bigger(3421) == 4123` and `assert next_bigger(13731) == 17133`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for better performance "time complexity wise", The approach would be to find the "key" of the algorithm. In this case you should ask yourself, what does it means to create the next bigger nummber? The answer is just as simple as a swap between two adjacent numbers. The code would be like this.

```
def next_bigger(n):
    num_string = list(str(n))
    for i in range(1, len(num_string)):
        if i == len(num_string):
            return -1

        #find two the two numbers one bigger than the other with the minimun order
        if num_string[-i] > num_string[-i-1]:

            compare_reference = num_string[-i]
            index_reference = -i

            #check if the current number is smaller than any of the tail 
            for k, current in enumerate(num_string[-i:]):
                if num_string[-i-1] < current and current < compare_reference:
                    compare_reference = current
                    index_reference = -i+k

            #interchange the locations:
            num_string[index_reference] = num_string[-i-1]
            num_string[-i-1] = compare_reference

            #check if the tail is larger than one digit
            if i > 1:
                #order the rest of the vector to create the smaller number (ordering it).
                lower_part_ordered = sort_ascendant(num_string[-i:])
            else:
                lower_part_ordered = [num_string[-i]]


            # create a string from the list
            return int("".join(num_string[:-i] + lower_part_ordered))        

    # no match found means a number like 65311
    return -1
```

Comment: [This gives `next_bigger(231) == 321` instead of `312`.](https://ideone.com/f3D4Or)

Comment: True, let me fix it. Its an index miss interpretation.

Comment: [This still gives `next_bigger(231) == 321`.](https://ideone.com/Kf4vlV) Switching two indices isn't enough.

Comment: You're right, i was missing a key point. I think the answere is complete now

Comment: [Still not quite.](https://ideone.com/v2y3fI) `next_bigger(35421)` should be `41235`, not `51234`. (Also you've got some index mismanagement problems, you try to use `lower_part_ordered` without defining it in the `i == 1` code path, and you could have used Python's built-in sort instead of writing your own.)

Comment: In the `35421` case, you need to switch the `3` with the next-higher digit that comes after it - the `4`, not the `5`. After that, the sequence of trailing digits can be put in ascending order just by reversing them, since they're already in descending order - a full sort isn't needed.

Comment: If there are multiple copies of the next-higher digit, like `354421`, you switch it with the last copy, producing `454321`, and then reverse the trailing digits, producing `412345`.

Comment: (Incidentally, C++ has this operation in the standard library, as [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).)

Comment: @JuanDavidRamirezVillegas Just changed the method slightly to get the right answer, have posted it below. Massive thanks for your help!!

Comment: `next_bigger(312)` for the version at the time of this comment, gives *"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lower_part_ordered' referenced before assignment"* for the line `return int("".join(num_string[:-i] + lower_part_ordered))`.

Comment: Corrected as @user2357112supportsMonica suggested. And tested with:
f(35421) --> 41235
f(454321) --> 512344
f(12) --> 21 
f(513342342342342342234) --> 513342342342342342243

Answer (score -1):

While not a way to increase the permutations function performance per se, this was the method I found to increase performance of the code. many thanks to all that offered help!

```
def next_bigger(n):
    num_string = list(str(n))
    a = []
    for i in range(1, len(num_string)):
        if i == len(num_string):
            return -1
        p = int(num_string[-i])
        q = int (num_string[-(i+1)])
        if p > q:
            a.append(num_string[:-(i+1)])
            lis = list(num_string[-(i+1):])
        if len(lis) > 1:
            lis2 = list(set(lis))
            lis2.sort()
            qindex = lis2.index(str(q))
            first = lis2[qindex+1]
            a[0].append(first)
            lis.remove(first)
            lis.sort()
        for j in range (len(lis)):
            a[0].append(lis[j])
        return int("".join(a[0]))
    return -1
```

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica passed all 150 tests? Which number inputs would not work?

Comment: As per @user2357112supportsMonica's link, `next_bigger(35421)` gives the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lis' referenced before assignment`. As do `next_bigger(111)` and `next_bigger(100)`. The error references the line `if len(lis) > 1:`. You also need to add checks for the trivial cases that can't be made bigger ie the `-1` results.